# java programs not running due to seting classpath

Tags: jdbc, java

i wanted to practice developing database programs in java so i set the classpath to `E:\software\installed\java\jre\lib` by declaring a new environmental variable `classpath` and gave value as `E:\software\installed\java\jre\lib` but now i am unable to run any program(not even non-database) i get an error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MysqlConnect
```

but when i delete the `classpath` variable i am able to run non-database programs. what is the possible problem and please let me know the solution. i have set path to `E:\software\installed\java\bin`

nothing is helping i tried using class path switch in java which is not helping (`java -cp C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5 MysqlConnect`) nor do setting path is helping (`set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%:C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5:C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar`) all are giving the error

`Error: Could not find or load main class MysqlConnect`

Comment: Lesson: don't set the environment classpath variable. Set it when calling your Java program via the -cp switch. Or better, create a Jar that uses a manifest with the classpath.

Comment: And, read the oracle docs regarding the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be defining a `classpath` for your programs using system variables. Standard way is to use the command line `-cp` or `-classpath` option. Take a look at what `java` prints out if you run it with no arguments.

You will find this mentioned in [**this tutorial**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html). It says:

`The preferred way to specify the class path is by using the -cp command line switch. This allows the CLASSPATH to be set individually for each application without affecting other applications. Setting the CLASSPATH can be tricky and should be performed with care`

Also, see how the default `CLASSPATH` environmetn variable has a `.` in it. If you still decide to add your classes in there, keep the `.` for other citizens and add your classes after a `;`, don't just overwrite the whole value.

Comment: `java -cp C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5 MysqlConnect` gives error `Error: Could not find or load main class MysqlConnect`

Comment: @Sar009, you will have to ensure your `MysqlConnect` is in that folder in its `.class` or `jar` form. And consider enclosing the path with the spaces in it using `""`. Also, your `MysqlConnect` class is likely defined in a package so you would need to refer to it using its "full qualified name", something like `home.sar009.MysqlConnect`.

Comment: i did this `C:\Users\sarad mohanan\Desktop\rose>java -cp "c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5" "c:\Users\sarad mohanan\Desktop\rose\MysqlConnect"` but still same error
`Error: Could not find or load main class` its not in package i also tried by keeping the `MysqlConnect.class` in `c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5` and changed the directory to that path and ran but still no help. i think java is accepting the -cp switch but after that it cant find the `MysqlConnect` class

Comment: Also what i found is after using -cp switch i cant execute any program not even non-database. it gives error `Error: Could not find or load main class classname`. so we have to solve the problem why -cp switch is not working then we can find the solution for the original problem

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [jdbc tutorial](http://www.raima.com/jdbc-tutorial/) for beginners that could help you find your answer.  If you skip to **step 14** it gives an example of how the classpath is used.  It is used as the first respondent is saying, by command line.

Hopefully this will help you in your particular situation. This tutorial is not database-specific so it will work with any type of database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

ok atlast i got the solution it should be typed as

`C:\Users\sarad mohanan\Desktop\rose>java -cp .;"c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar" MysqlConnect
MySQL Connect Example.
Connected to the database
Disconnected from database`

we have to add `.;` before the original path `.` holds default classpath. pravel veller had said it previously but i didn't understand it then

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose using a good tool like Eclipse. You can test the CLASSPATH indirectly and your environment by adding or removing jar files and libraries.

Obviously, the libraries in your default CLASSPATH is different than the one in your E drive. You may compare the files by knowing your CLASSPATH. In Windows, do "echo %CLASSPATH%".

Eclipse can help you by experimenting without rebooting or any annoying steps. And this stuff is not easy.

Answer (score -1):

Crete o set environment variable if you use windows `JAVA_HOME=E:\software\installed\java`, and after append the Java bin directory `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`. Note that paths are separated from each other with semicolons `(;)` I hope help you. That's work for me !!!. I don't understand. What happen?.